# Orthogonal complex structures for indefinite inner products

Tags: linear-algebra, riemannian-geometry

Suppose that $(V,b)$ is a real even-dimensional ($n=2k$) vector space with a nondenegenerate symmetric bilinear form $b$.

Question : Is there (always) a linear map $J:V\to V$  such that

1. $J^2 = -I$
2. $J\in O(V,b)$

I know that in the case of a positive-definite form $b$, such a (orthogonal complex) structure always exists, but I was not able to see how to extend that (or prove that we cannot extend that) to the non-positive-definite case, or find references for that question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The existence of a complex structure depends on the signature $(p,q)$ of $b$. If $p$ and $q$ are even, then there does exist a complex structure. Within $O(p,q)$ you can find a copy of $O(p) \times O(q)$, which reduces to the case you know.

On the other hand, if $p$ is odd (so also $q$ is odd) then there won't be a complex structure.

For example, let $(V,b)$ be $\mathbb{R}^2$ with
$$ b(v,w) = v^T \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} w .$$
If $J \colon V \to V$ satisfies $\det (J)= \pm 1$ and
$$ J^t \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} J = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} $$
then either
$$ J = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ b & a \end{pmatrix} \text{ and } \det (J)=1,  \text{ or } \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ -b & -a \end{pmatrix} \text{ and } \det(J)=-1 .$$
You can check that if you further impose $J^2=-1$ there will be no solutions.